# Why are photos arranging in column rather than grid (HTML + CSS)?

Tags: html, css

Okay, so I'm following a Treehouse tutorial on making a simple portfolio website. They have photos that should be arranged in a grid. I'm using videos instead, but I tried switching for pictures, which made no difference. My Photos are all still in a column on the left, then the footer is to the right where some of the photos should be. I would imagine I'm missing some kind of closing tag or something, but I can't find it. Would you mind taking a look at it? Thanks.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Carter Goff | Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700|Oswald:300,400,700' rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <a href="index.html"  id = "logo">
        <h1>Carter Goff</h1>
        <h2>Choreographer</h2>
      </a>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="portfolio.html" class="selected">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <section>
        <ul id = "gallery">
          <li>
            <a href="vid/vid1.mp4">
              <video controls>
                <source src="vid/vid1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
              </video>
            </a>
            <a href="vid/vid1.mp4">
              <video controls>
                <source src="vid/vid1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              Your browser does not support the video tag.
              </video>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <footer>
        <a href="http://instagram.com/cartergoffofficial"><img src="img/instagram.png" alt="Instagram Logo"></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/carter.goff.52"><img src="img/facebook.png" alt ="Facebook Logo"></a>
        <p>&copy; 2016 Carter Goff</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And CSS:

```
/************************
GENERAL
*************************/

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 5%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

video{
  max-width: 100%;
}



/************************
HEADING
************************/

#logo {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  margin: 15px 0;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 0.8em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  margin: -5px 0 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}



/************************
NAVIGATION
************************/

nav {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
}



/************************
FOOTER
************************/

footer {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 50px;
  color: #ccc;
}



/************************
PAGE: PORTFOLIO
************************/

#gallery {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#gallery li {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 2.5%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #bdc3c7;
}

#gallery li a p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5%;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: #bdc3c7
}


/************************
COLORS
************************/

/* site body */
body{
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #b3b3b3;
}

/* pink header */
header{
  border-color: #ffb3ff;
  background: #000000;
}

/* nav background on mobile */
nav{
  background: #ffb3ff;
}

/* logo text */
h1, h2 {
  color: #fff;
}

/* links */
a {
  color: #00ffb3;
}

/* nav links */
nav a, nav a:visited {
  color: #000;
}

/* selected nav link */
nav a.selected, nav a:hover {
  color: #b300b3
}
```

Comment: need a demo for tracing your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed to split the images into 2 "li" instead of having both inside the same "li"

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have one `li` with two videos in there, but by looking at the css I see you have `li {float: left; width: 45%; margin: 2,5%}` and that would only make sense if there's more than one li, so I'll assume you want two `li`'s with one video in each. If I change your HTML to the structure I just said your css works perfectly:

```css
/************************
GENERAL
*************************/

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 5%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

video{
  max-width: 100%;
}



/************************
HEADING
************************/

#logo {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  margin: 15px 0;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 0.8em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  margin: -5px 0 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}



/************************
NAVIGATION
************************/

nav {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
}



/************************
FOOTER
************************/

footer {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 50px;
  color: #ccc;
}



/************************
PAGE: PORTFOLIO
************************/

#gallery {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#gallery li {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 2.5%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #bdc3c7;
}

#gallery li a p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5%;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: #bdc3c7
}


/************************
COLORS
************************/

/* site body */
body{
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #b3b3b3;
}

/* pink header */
header{
  border-color: #ffb3ff;
  background: #000000;
}

/* nav background on mobile */
nav{
  background: #ffb3ff;
}

/* logo text */
h1, h2 {
  color: #fff;
}

/* links */
a {
  color: #00ffb3;
}

/* nav links */
nav a, nav a:visited {
  color: #000;
}

/* selected nav link */
nav a.selected, nav a:hover {
  color: #b300b3
}
```

```html
    <header>
      <a href="index.html"  id = "logo">
        <h1>Carter Goff</h1>
        <h2>Choreographer</h2>
      </a>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="portfolio.html" class="selected">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <section>
        <ul id = "gallery">
          <li>
            <a href="vid/vid1.mp4">
              <video controls>
                <source src="vid/vid1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
              </video>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="vid/vid1.mp4">
              <video controls>
                <source src="vid/vid1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              Your browser does not support the video tag.
              </video>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <footer>
        <a href="http://instagram.com/cartergoffofficial"><img src="img/instagram.png" alt="Instagram Logo"></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/carter.goff.52"><img src="img/facebook.png" alt ="Facebook Logo"></a>
        <p>&copy; 2016 Carter Goff</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
```

PS: I took the liberty to add `overflow: hidden;` to the `#gallery` to clear your floats.

PS2: I ran your code through the w3c validator to check for missing closing tabs. It's a nice tool and helps quite a lot, get used to use it: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input . It also gives suggestions, for example your `section`s are missing headings.

Answer (score 0):

Both your videos are on the same `li`. But as per your style-sheet definitions you should have them in seperate `li`'s.

**Below code**

```
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
          </a>
          <a href="vid/vid1.mp4">
```

**should be changed to**

```
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="vid/vid1.mp4">
```

```css
/************************
GENERAL
*************************/

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
}
#wrapper {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 5%;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
video {
  max-width: 100%;
}
/************************
HEADING
************************/

#logo {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
h1 {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  margin: 15px 0;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 0.8em;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  margin: -5px 0 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}
/************************
NAVIGATION
************************/

nav {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
}
/************************
FOOTER
************************/

footer {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 50px;
  color: #ccc;
}
/************************
PAGE: PORTFOLIO
************************/

#gallery {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#gallery li {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 2.5%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #bdc3c7;
}
#gallery li a p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5%;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: #bdc3c7
}
/************************
COLORS
************************/

/* site body */

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #b3b3b3;
}
/* pink header */

header {
  border-color: #ffb3ff;
  background: #000000;
}
/* nav background on mobile */

nav {
  background: #ffb3ff;
}
/* logo text */

h1,
h2 {
  color: #fff;
}
/* links */

a {
  color: #00ffb3;
}
/* nav links */

nav a,
nav a:visited {
  color: #000;
}
/* selected nav link */

nav a.selected,
nav a:hover {
  color: #b300b3
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Carter Goff | Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700|Oswald:300,400,700' rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a href="index.html" id="logo">
      <h1>Carter Goff</h1>
      <h2>Choreographer</h2>
    </a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html" class="selected">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <section>
      <ul id="gallery">
        <li>
          <a href="vid/vid1.mp4">
            <video controls>
              <source src="vid/vid1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="vid/vid1.mp4">
            <video controls>
              <source src="vid/vid1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <footer>
      <a href="http://instagram.com/cartergoffofficial">
        <img src="img/instagram.png" alt="Instagram Logo">
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/carter.goff.52">
        <img src="img/facebook.png" alt="Facebook Logo">
      </a>
      <p>&copy; 2016 Carter Goff</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```